# Accessing a variable in a subclass through a superclass method (Java)

Tags: java, methods, superclass

I am building two classes: `Person` and `namedPerson`. `Person` is the superclass of `namedPerson`. I need the method `printPerson` to print out the first and last name of a `namedPerson`, but `Person` can only receive the last name, and `namedPerson` receives both first and last names. My code is as follows:

```
public abstract class Person {

   String Lastname;
   String Name;

   public Person(String Lastname){
     this.Lastname = Lastname;
   }

   public void printPerson() {
     System.out.println("Name: " + Name);
     System.out.println("Last name: " + Lastname);
   }
```

Here is `namedPerson`:

```
public class namedPerson extends Person {

   String Lastname;
   String Name;

   public namedPerson(String Lastname){
     super(Lastname);
     this.Name = "Bob";
   }
```

When I do the following:

```
namedPerson Bob = new namedPerson("Smith");
Bob.printPerson();
```

I get:

```
Name: null
Last name: Smith
```

When I need to get:

```
Name: Bob
Last name: Smith
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since `namedPerson` also has `Lastname` and `Name` you can just remove these fields for this class and call the  super constructor like this: `super(Lastname, "Bob")`; this reduces redundancy in your code. I would also recommend sticking to the naming conventions and using class names starting with an uppercase letter (`NamedPerson`) and field names starting with a lowercase letter (`lastname`, `name`).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are redeclaring the instance variables Lastname and Name inside the sub-class which makes no sense because you already inherited them from the superclass.

All you have to do is to remove them from the sub-class:

```
public class namedPerson extends Person {

   public namedPerson(String Lastname){
     super(Lastname);
     this.Name = "Bob";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public abstract class Person {

    String Lastname;
    

    public Person(String Lastname) {
        this.Lastname = Lastname;
    }

    public void printPerson() {
        System.out.println("Last name: " + Lastname);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NamedPerson namedPerson = new NamedPerson("firstName", "Name");
        namedPerson.printPerson();
    }
}

class NamedPerson extends Person {

    String name;

    public NamedPerson(String Lastname, String name) {
        super(Lastname);
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void printPerson() {
        super.printPerson();
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    }
}
```